# Boundaries of Sets U and V

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space and let $U$ and $V$ be subsets of $X$.

a.) Then $Bd(U) − Bd(V) ⊆ Bd(U − V)$.

b.) Then $Bd(U − V) ⊆ Bd(U) − Bd(V)$.

I have come up with a pretty clear counterexample for (b) but cannot find any counterexamples for (a).  Every example I try always results in $Bd(U) − Bd(V) ⊆ Bd(U − V)$.

I think (a) is true.  Not looking for a complete proof but confirmation that I am correct.  If not, please provide some guidance on where I can start for a counterexample.

Comment: How about concentric disks in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ for part a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample to (a):

[image]

...more characters to satisfy minimum...